# Interrupt signal gets lost on FREERTOS

Tags: c, stm32, freertos

I have a continuously rotating servo motor that is connected to the rotary encoder which calculates the exact angle of rotation. I need to stop the spinning of the servo motor once it rotates 90 degrees.

I am using an interrupt signal to calculate the rotation angle of my rotary encoder. Sometimes some of the interrupt calls get lost, so the angle is calculated incorrectly, I think probably it happens when another process (servo motor) is running while the interrupt happens. When I rotate the rotary encoder by hand it always shows the correct angle.

Is there a way to queue those interruptions somehow so they will never be lost?
I am using FreeRTOS and STM32

Here is the pseudocode of my interrupt handler.

```
 volatile int rotationAngle = 0;

 void handleRotaryEncoderInterrupt(uint8_t index) {
     GPIO_PinState clk = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(clkPort, clkPin);
     GPIO_PinState dt = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(dtPort, dtPin);

     if(clk == GPIO_PIN_SET && dt == GPIO_PIN_RESET) {
        rotationCount++;
        rotationAngle = rotationCount * STEPS_TO_ANGLE;
     }
 }
```

And another task that runs periodically and stops the servo motor when it rotates 90 degrees.

```
void myTask() 
{
    while(1) 
   {
        myServo.duty = MOVE_FORWARD;

        while(rotationAngle % 90 != 0)
        {
            osDelay(100);
        }

        myServo.duty = STOP;
        
        osDelay(10000);
   }
}
```

Comment: Interrups from mechanical encoder aren't so fast to be lost in hardware. Likely they are lost because of bugs in the code. But it's difficult to find a bug in code not seeing code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why do you check `rotationAngle % 90` in separate task? You can check it after every increment and run `myServo.duty = STOP` in handler. Two or more interrups may occure during `osDelay(100)`, so polling with delay looks like bad design.

Comment: @dimich I moved it to a separate task, to make sure it doesn't slow down the interrupt handler.

Comment: @Davithbul Let `rotationAngle` is e.g. `89` during comparison. Then `osDelay(100)` is invoked. If two interrupts occured at that time you get `rotationAngle == 91` and lose event. Interrupt is not lost, you just missed value you expect because of polling. Either do job in interrupt handler or do something like `if (rotationAngle >= 90) ...`. I'd suggest to review your algorithm of angle threshold detection on higher level, interrupts are not to blame here.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but the problem is not that it misses the angle to stop the servo, but rather that the angle is calculated incorrectly. So interrupt is not getting the right signal when myTask is also running.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a semaphore to control the task from the ISR. A semaphore could be released each time the angle is `0 % 90`:

```c
SemaphoreHandle_t xSemaphore = NULL;
StaticSemaphore_t xSemaphoreBuffer;

volatile int rotationAngle = 0;

void handleRotaryEncoderInterrupt(uint8_t index) {
    GPIO_PinState clk = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(clkPort, clkPin);
    GPIO_PinState dt = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(dtPort, dtPin);

    if(clk == GPIO_PIN_SET && dt == GPIO_PIN_RESET) {
        rotationAngle = rotationCount * STEPS_TO_ANGLE;
        if( 0 == (rotationAngle%90)) {
            xSemaphoreGiveFromISR(xSemaphore, NULL);
        }        
    }
}
 
void myTask() 
{
    // create the semaphore
    xSemaphore = xSemaphoreCreateBinaryStatic(&xSemaphoreBuffer);
    
    // register the ISR (not sure of the exact syntax)
    register_interrupt(handleRotaryEncoderInterrupt);

    while(1) 
    {
        myServo.duty = MOVE_FORWARD;
        // wait for the semaphore to be released
        if (xSemaphoreTake(xSemaphore, portMAX_DELAY) == pdTRUE) {
            myServo.duty = STOP;
            osDelay(10000);         
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how is it related to the question?

Comment: @0___________ The problem was the `osDelay(100);` that could miss the angle reaching  `0 % 90`. I propose instead of pulling + wait to use semaphore to be sure to never lose such event.

Comment: I see your point, but the problem is not that it misses the angle to stop the servo, but rather that the angle is calculated incorrectly. So interrupt is not getting the right signal when myTask is running.